# Trigger an Azure Function from Power BI

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-functions, powerbi-embedded

We are using Power BI Embedded to display data which is coming from Cosmos Db. We have to try the following thing

1. Display a Bar chart with an aggregated value
2. Display the detailed table based on the Bar chart.
3. Have a checkbox in the table (there is a GUID). Select multiple GUIDs and on a click this will trigger an Azure Function and send the GUID as an input to the function.

We are able to perform #1 and #2. Is it possible to achieve functionality #3 using Power BI Embedded.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this by integrating with Power Automate. See this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/power-bi-automate-visual?tabs=powerbi-desktop

1. Create a Flow with a HTTP connector that can trigger your Azure function
2. Connect this Flow to the Power Automate visualization in Power BI

The Flow should be able to accept contextual data upon triggering, e.g. this GUID, to pass on to the Azure function. You assign the GUID column (or measure that calculates the selected GUID) to the Power Automate visual.

Comment: Though this seems a possible solution, I see two challenges. 1. The feature is in Preview and 2. This does not support embedded Analytics. Is there any other alternative

Comment: Embedded Analytics?

Comment: Right - it appears this doesn’t work properly for Embedded Power BI reports. If you can create a HTTP trigger that can pass the selected GUID in the URL you can use a regular button in Power BI and assign an URL action to it - use a measure to conditionally calculate the URL based on selection. However, this method probably makes auth an issue?